# Date column not being found when delete

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

I have this statement which does not delete any rows.

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE
    datecolumn = sysdate + 100;
```

However, the below one deletes 57K rows, as I would expect. Why is this happening? Datecolumn in mytable is stored as DATE variable type.

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE
    to_char(datecolumn, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_char(sysdate + 100, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most probably because `DATECOLUMN` contains a "truncated" date, i.e. value that doesn't have a time component (because it is set to 00:00:00).

`Sysdate`, on the other hand, returns full date + time value, so there's no match and `DELETE` doesn't delete anything.

Instead of your 2nd code (which uses `TO_CHAR` and prevents possible index on `datecolumn` to be used), modify your 1st query a little bit:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE datecolumn = trunc(sysdate) + 100;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to truncate both fields, but that's definitely why my delete was not working.

Comment: _"I had to truncate both fields, "_  Then your datecolumn _did_ have a non-zero time, but of course the odds of any specific one having exactly the same _time_ as SYSDATE  (down to the second) are astronomical.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, `date` -- despite its name -- has a time component.  `sysdate` -- despite its name -- also has a time component.

So, the first version is comparing *exactly* the date plus time and there are no matches.  The second is comparing only the date part.

Note that converting dates to strings is generally unnecessary.

You could write the second to be more performance as:

```
where datecolumn >= trunc(sysdate) + interval '100' day and
      datecolumn < trunc(sysdate) + interval '101' day;
```

This makes it easier for the optimizer, because there are no functions on the column.